# Blank character when copying table data

Tags: html, html-table, tailwind-css

Using Tailwind, I am trying to make a table where data is aligned by the decimal point and I came to a solution but when I copy and paste the table data I get a blank character in the mix. The data looks perfectly fine but when I copy and paste I get this

`500    .00`

I'm not sure what is causing this and I'm not sure how to fix it, any help is much appreciated.
https://play.tailwindcss.com/p6dMeTT0DX